# UPX bad image on launch and notcompressible exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, upx

The script is super simple and works with no UPX.

```
import selenium
import scipy
import pandas as pd
print('Testing123')
```

Upon launch I get [bad image](https://ibb.co/cpjQC6)

`pyinstaller myfile.py --upx-dir=C:\upx394w --onedir`

Does not work when launching exe, I am using windows 64bit.

`pyinstaller az1.py --onedir –noupx` (Az1.exe) [Works]

Now I run and get bad image.  Only real issue could be: NotCompressibleException which could be issue but it appears to be compressed otherwise [(full command line output)](https://pastebin.com/SVERrsU1):

Note worthy:

```
    upx: C:\Users\H0u\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache01_py36_64bit\api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll: NotCompressibleException
    69790 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

[File](https://ufile.io/ubrhq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is weird.  This is common issue see here:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1565

Deleting  vcruntime140.dll fixes this.  Will do further tests, but this is fixed by deleting that file causing issue (not sure if safe) but works.